# sustain vs. retain

Tags: verbs

I'm japanese junior high school student.I can't understand what the difference in meaning is between retain and sustain.

They are said 維持する in japanese.
Please tell me the diffence.

Comment: You should look them up in an English dictionary; if you still have questions, we will be here.

Comment: As @Xanne said, you should look them up on a dictionary (e.g. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/retain) and then ask what specifically you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

If I retain something it means that I keep it.  I do not, for example, sell it or give it away.

To sustain something means I persist with it.  If I make a sustained effort to do something it means that I keep trying. A sustained attack is one that goes on and on.

Answer (score 1):

Retain means, as Aethelbald has said, keep

"To sustain," however, does not merely mean persist.  [ODO on sustain](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sustain)

> sustain verb [with object]
>
> 1   Strengthen or support physically or mentally.
>      ‘this thought had sustained him throughout the years’
>
> 1.1 Bear (the weight of an object) without breaking or falling.
>      ‘he sagged against her so that she could barely sustain his weight’
>      figurative ‘his health will no longer enable him to sustain the heavy burdens of office’
>
> 2 Undergo or suffer (something unpleasant, especially an injury) ‘he
>   sustained severe head injuries’
>
> 3 Cause to continue for an extended period or without interruption. ‘he
>   cannot sustain a normal conversation’